# Replicating data between multiple Hadoop clusters residing in different data centers

Tags: hadoop, disaster-recovery

I was wondering what would be the best way to replicate the data present in a Hadoop cluster H1 in data center DC1 to another Hadoop cluster H2 in data center DC2 (warm backup preferably). I know that Hadoop does data replication and the number of copies of the data created is decided by the replication factor set in hdfs-site.xml. I have a few questions related to this

- Would it make sense to have the data nodes of one cluster be spread across both data centers so that the data nodes for H1 would be present in both DC1 and DC2. If this makes sense and is viable, then does it mean we do not need H2?
- Would it make sense to have the namenodes and datanodes distributed across both data centers rather than having only the datanodes distributed across both data centers?

I have also heard people use distcp and many tools build on top of distcp. But distcp does lazy backups and would prefer warm backups over cold ones.

Some people suggest using Kafka for this but I am not sure how to go about using it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to protect against.  If you want to protect against site failure, distcp seems to be the only option for cross datacenter replication.  However, as you pointed out, distcp has limitations.  You can use snapshots to protect against user mistakes or application corruptions because replication or multiple replicas will not protect against that.  Other commercial tools are available for automating the backup process as well if you don't want to write code and maintain it.